# spring mongo creating like query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I can match starting of string i.e clo with keywords and it gives me correct result  `db.post.find({"keywords":"/^clo/"}).pretty()` When I tried to write same query using spring mongo.It not working properly. It gives result as % string %. i.e. matches anywhere in string. I am trying to match only at starting  . my code is

```
String pattern = "/^" + keyword + "/";
Criteria criteria2 = Criteria.where("keywords").is(keyword).regex(pattern);
```

Where I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do it like this:

   `Query.query(Criteria.where("keywords").regex("^clo"))`
2. Or use it as native query:

   `new BasicQuery("{'keywords' : '/^clo/'}")`

Method `is()` provides the full `equals`, `regex()` has to be without `/` wrappers.

That's is your issue.